# Lists in Scala - plus colon vs double colon (+: vs ::)

Tags: scala

I am little bit confused about [+:](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#+:(elem:A):List[A]) and [::](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#::(x:A):List[A]) operators that are available.

It looks like both of them gives the same results.

```
scala> List(1,2,3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> 0 +: res0
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)

scala> 0 :: res0
res2: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

For my novice eye source code for both methods looks similar (plus-colon method has additional condition on generics with use of builder factories).

Which one of these methods should be used and when?

Comment: A good place to begin: try the same thing with `Seq` instead of `List`...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`+:` works with any kind of collection, while `::` is specific implementation for `List`. 
If you look at the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L198) for `+:` closely, you will notice that it actually calls `::` when the expected return type is `List`. That is because `::` is implemented more efficiently for the `List` case: it simply connects the new head to the existing list and returns the result, which  is a constant-time operation, as opposed to linear copying the entire collection in the generic case of `+:`.

`+:` on the other hand, takes `CanBuildFrom`, so you can do fancy (albeit, not looking as nicely in this case) things like:

```
val foo: Array[String] = List("foo").+:("bar")(breakOut)
```

(It's pretty useless in this particular case, as you could start with the needed type to begin with, but the idea is you can prepend and element to a collection, and change its type in one "go", avoiding an additional copy).